# Is it true that $V$ and $V^*$ are naturally isomorphic as finite vector spaces if $V$ is equipped with an inner product?

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, inner-products

This is a homework question from my differentiable manifolds class:

In general we know that if $\dim V<\infty$ then $V$ and $V^*$ are isomorphic because any two vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic. But the fact that any two vector spaces with the same dimension are isomorphic depends on our choice of bases for them, therefore this isomorphism is not natural in general.

Now suppose that $V$ is an inner product space. So, there's a non-degenerate bilinar form on $V$ like $<\cdot,\cdot> :V\times V\to\mathbb{R}$. Can $V$ and $V^*$ be shown to be naturally isomorphic now?

Here's my thought:

Now that $V$ has been equipped with an inner product we have this natural pairing $T$ that gives us our desired coordinate-free isomorphism:

$T: V \to V^*$

$ v \mapsto f_v(x) = <v,x>$

1. $\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \forall v_1,v_2 \in V:$

   $$\forall x \in V: f_{v_1+\lambda v_2}(x) = <v_1+\lambda v_2,x> = <v_1,x>+\lambda <v_2,x>=f_{v_1}(x)+\lambda f_{v_2}(x)$$

Therefore $T(v_1+\lambda v_2)=f_{v_1+\lambda v_2}=f_{v_1}+\lambda f_{v_2}=T(v_1)+\lambda T(v_2)$ and $T$ is a linear transformation.

1. $\ker{T}=\{ v: T(v)=0 \}=\{v: f_v(x)=<v,x>=0  \text{ forall x in V}\}=\{0\} $ because $<\cdot,\cdot>$ has been assumed to be non-degenerate. Therefore $T$ is one-to-one.
2. $\operatorname{Image}{T}=V^*$ because of rank-nullity theorem and the fact that $\dim{V^*}=\dim{V}$. More precisely, $\dim{V} = \ker{T} + \operatorname{rank}{T} = 0 + \operatorname{rank}{T} \implies \operatorname{rank}{T} = n \implies \operatorname{Image}{T}=V^*$

Therefore $T$ is a one-to-one surjective linear transformation that has been defined without reference to any basis for $V$.

Now how can I show that this construction is really a natural isomorphism in the category of finite vector spaces? I mean, assuming that my construction is correct, how can I show that it fits the definition of a natural transformation in category theory?

This question has a sequel that asks me to prove several isomorphisms about the vector space $\Lambda^k(V)$ like: $\Lambda^k(V) \cong \Lambda^{n-k}(V)$. But first I need to understand this one carefully I think.

Comment: Does the question really ask for the *categorical* notion of naturality?  Because the "identity" functor is covariant and the "dualization" one is contravariant, so they can't actually be naturally isomorphic.

Comment: @RyanReich: No, it only asks us to show that $V$ and $V^*$ are naturally isomorphic in the sense that we don't need to involve bases and coordinates to construct an isomorphism between them, or at least that's what I've understood so far from the class. My understanding of the concept of a natural isomorphism is very shaky I guess. The category theory part comes from my own curiosity because I'm trying to understand how these two notions of naturality relate to each other.

Comment: @RyanReich: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinatural_transformation

Comment: this might help http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation#Example:_dual_of_a_finite-dimensional_vector_space

Comment: If you restrict the morphisms to be isometric isomorphisms, then the category is self-dual, and $V \to V^*$ really becomes a natural isomorphism.

Comment: @ZhenLin: So what I have constructed so far is not really a natural isomorphism if I don't restrict my maps to isometric transformations?

Comment: @math.noob No, and the way you should think about this is that you required the *additional* data (on top of bare vector spaces) of an inner product.  Therefore, you need to impose a compatibility requirement on your morphisms to respect this data, and a morphism that respects an inner product is an isometry.

Comment: @RyanReich: That makes perfect sense. Is it possible to use a categorical argument using diagram chasing to show that our morphisms should be orthonormal transformations?

Comment: @math.noob I would say that this kind of thing is more meta-categorical than actually.  See, it is *possible* to define a category whose objects are inner product spaces but whose morphisms are all linear transformations; it's just the "wrong" category.

Comment: @RyanReich: Yes, you're right. Thanks. I guess I get it now. So, If we restrict our morphisms to orthonormal transformations (i.e. inner product preserving maps in the category) is my argument correct then?

Comment: @math.noob You haven't given an argument for naturality, that I can see.  Your argument that it is an isomorphism is of course correct.  To show naturality, you should expand on Zhen Lin's comment: define a self-duality of the category of inner product spaces which, on objects, takes a vector space to its dual (you should figure out what it does to morphisms) and then show that your transformation is a natural isomorphism of this with the identity functor.  The fact that it is a canonical (i.e. basis-independent) construction will, naturally, be crucial.